# .net core 3.1.1 not on EC2 instance - can't install app

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, .net-core

I'm trying to deploy a new .net core 3.1.1 app via Elasticbeanstalk and I'm getting a compile error.

```
The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '3.1.0' was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      2.1.13 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
      2.1.14 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
      2.2.7 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
      2.2.8 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
      3.0.0 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.
```

Logged on to the instance and tried to download the 3.1.1 version and ran into a security issue. "You are not permitted to save this content" or something to that effect. Verified that 3.0.1 is the latest version.

Any ideas on where to go next? Not sure how to install 3.1

Thanks.

Comment: Only way is that you need to ask that EC2 host for permission to download and install 3.1.0 and 3.1.1 in that server.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else runs into this. IE was blocking the download. Just had to change the security setting on IE to allow downloads. Downloaded the 3.1.1 version of core and it worked.